# Wrong number of objects being returned

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this MATLab code to count the number of objects in the image. There are two objects in the image I am choosing (a car and a cyclist). However, the program is returning a wrong output saying there are 0 objects. Can someone find the error in the code? Thanks.

The logic behind the code is:
1. Take two input images are given, one without objects and one with objects.
2. Convert the input images from RGB to Gray scale.
3. Compare the two images and find the difference.
4. Convert the image obtained to binary.
5. In the image, only open the blobs whose area is greater than 4000.
6. Display the count and density.

```
clc;

MV = imread('car.png');                                         %To read image
MV1 = imread('backgnd.png');
A = double(rgb2gray(MV));                                       %convert to gray
B= double(rgb2gray(MV1));           %convert 2nd image to gray
[height, width] = size(A);          %image size?
h1 = figure(1);

%Foreground Detection

thresh=11;
fr_diff = abs(A-B);
for j = 1:width
    for k = 1:height
        if (fr_diff(k,j)>thresh)
            fg(k,j) = A(k,j);
        else
            fg(k,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end
subplot(2,2,1) , imagesc(MV), title ({'Orignal Frame'});
subplot(2,2,2) , imshow(mat2gray(A)), title ('converted Frame');
subplot(2,2,3) , imshow(mat2gray(B)), title ('BACKGND Frame ');
sd=imadjust(fg);               % adjust the image intensity values to the color map
level=graythresh(sd);
m=imnoise(sd,'gaussian',0,0.025);       % apply Gaussian noise
k=wiener2(m,[5,5]);             %filtering using Weiner filter
bw=im2bw(k,level);
bw2=imfill(bw,'holes');
bw3 = bwareaopen(bw2,5000);
labeled = bwlabel(bw3,8);
cc=bwconncomp(bw3);
Densityoftraffic = cc.NumObjects/(size(bw3,1)*size(bw3,2));
blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeled,'all');
numberofcars = size(blobMeasurements, 1);
subplot(2,2,4) , imagesc(labeled), title ({'Foreground'});
hold off;
disp(numberofcars);             % display number of cars
disp(Densityoftraffic);             %display number of vehicles
```

[An empty image(of a road) with no objects(vehicles) in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q2KD.png)
[An image of the same road but with 2 objects(car and cyclist) in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is1rN.png)

Comment: Have you tried showing any of the intermediate results using something like `imshow()` or `imagesc()`, specifically `m`, `k`, `bw`, `bw2` and `bw3`?

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked! Seems like the area I was keeping as a threshold in bwareaopen() was a too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This it will help you in an optimize manner

```
        clc
        clear all
        close all

        im1 = imread('image1.png');
        im2 = imread('image2.png');

        gray1 = double(rgb2gray(im1));
        gray2 = double(rgb2gray(im2));

        absDif = mat2gray(abs(gray1 - gray2));

        figure,imshow(absDif,[])

        absDfbw = im2bw(absDif,0.9*graythresh(absDif));
        figure,imshow(absDfbw,[])

        absDfbw = bwareaopen(absDfbw,25);

        absDfbw = imclose(absDfbw,strel('disk',5));

        figure,imshow(absDfbw,[])
```

Results are:

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Thanks a  lot, this really helped.